# How to find a specific row in Excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, find, vlookup, lookup

I am looking for some formula in Excel like

```
give me the number of the row which its first column is 5 and its second is 3
```

I have searched the web but I have found lookup, search, find and ... which I couldn't use them for this sake.

Also, in some similar question someone suggested Access which can perform it easily. But I wonder if there is an Excel formula doing this?

For example, I have the following list

```
            Column-A     Column-B      Column-C
row-1       user ID      item ID       suggested cost
row-2       1            1             1000
row-3       1            2             500
row-4       2            1             11100
row-5       2            2             490
```

if my final goal is knowing the suggested cost of user 2 on item 2, first I want to find the row-5 and then refer it by index(A1:C5, found row, 3)

Comment: Give us some exmaple's. Your query doesn't seems to be very clear.

Comment: I wrote the example in an edit

Comment: Sorry no idea what you are asking for. Are you sure the table fits to your description?

Comment: My main question is a formula to which we give the values of two first columns and it searches the list and gives the value of the related third column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple formula:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,G1,B:B,G2)
```

Put the User ID into G1, and put the Item ID into G2 (or change the formula to suit your needs). This formula will sum C columns values of all the rows where the User ID and Item ID match. Hopefully there will be only one possible cost. If there's duplicates, it will give you the sum of the duplicates!

You could use conditional formatting to mark any duplicates on your data table to prevent this problem.